# Change TextBlock foreground color on Mouseover in GridView

Tags: windows-8, microsoft-metro, winrt-xaml

I have created an app starting from the Grid App template (C#/XAML) of Visual Studio 2012. I'm using the Light Theme and I have customized the GridViewItem brushes so that the color blue is used when I move the mouse over an item.

Now I would like to change the foreground color of the text that is shown in the GridView when the mouse is over the item, using white to make it more readable. Is it possible, considering that the layout of GridView items is defined in a DataTemplate?

Answer (score 0):

Here is an [blog post](http://labs.vectorform.com/2012/09/styling-a-gridviewitem-in-winrt/) which demonstrates styling of GridViewItem.

Comment: I have already seen this article, but my problem isn't about styling a GridViewItem (that I have already done), but changing a prooperty on a TextBlock inside the GridView ItemTemplate when the mouse is mover the GridViewItem.

Comment: One option for it is, get the data template for GridView in current page and attach PointerEntered and PointerExited events for textblocks to make the color change. I know, this is not that elegant, but it works.